# Como utilizar Linq2db.Firebird?

Tags: c#, firebird

baixei o `Linq2db.Firebird` utilizando o seguinte código:

```
Install-Package linq2db.Firebird
```

A instalação foi efetuada com sucesso, porém não estou conseguindo encontrar no Visual Studio, nada referente à ele, não sei como utilizar e não encontrei um tutorial bom na internet.

Alguém que usa o ele, pode me explicar como uso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um trabalho a pouco tempo e realmente foi difícil conseguir material auxiliar na internet, usei como base um trabalho pronto disponível no GitHub:

https://github.com/linq2db/examples

Comment: fiz o passo 1 (copiei e colei o arquivo numa pasta chamada DataModels). no passo 2, fiz a configuração assim: `LoadFirebirdMetadata("localhost", @"E:\OneDrive\VisualStudio\BancoFirebird\BancoFirebird\DADOS.GDB");` mas estou recebendo um erro na quarta linha que diz que o `namespace LinqToDb` não foi encontrado. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Consulte os arquivos dentro da pasta "DataModels" dentro do projeto no github e confira se o namespace no arquivo TestData.tt esta igual ao da classe TestData.generated.cs, acho que estão com nomes diferentes no  seu projeto.

Comment: continua sem encontrar o LinqToBd, já fiz várias modificações nos nomes e já botei o endereço direto do arquivo, mesmo assim ele não acha